# Ordenar tallas Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Quiero organizar las tallas en el orden que es ejemplo S-L-XL.

Leí esto (https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_sort_list.asp), pero no me sirve ya que lo organiza es alfabéticamente.

Cual seria la mejor forma de hacerlo?

Gracias.

```
<select id="pa_talla" class="" name="attribute_pa_talla" data-attribute_name="attribute_pa_talla" data-show_option_none="yes">
  <option value="">Elige una opción</option>
  <option value="l" class="attached enabled">L</option>
  <option value="s" class="attached enabled">S</option>
  <option value="xl" class="attached enabled">XL</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Saludos. Lo que leiste no es que no te sirva; realmente no aplica a tu caso, te falto aplicar tu lógica. Dependiendo tu origen; si es fijo colocarlas tu en orden que necesitas; si proviene de una BD; deberás agregar un campo (digamos) `orden` (puede ser) de tipo `entero` al cual le pones de **1** a **N** según corresponda quieres aparezca; asi con `ORDER BY` lo recibes como se desplegaran.

Comment: @BetaM Si, señor organizarlo de forma personalizada.

Comment: @RobertoLeOr  es una lista de wp, entonces no tengo control de la consulta, por eso recurro al js

Comment: Saludos de nuevo. Si el `<select>` así te llega; será necesario (si hay forma) que antes de que el usuario interactue obtengas datos de los `<option>`, vacíes el `<select>`, ordenes los datos (según requieras; el proceso puede ser diverso) y vuelvas a poblar el `<select>`.

Comment: ¿Quieres ordenar la lista, o unos datos según el valor de la lista seleccionado?

Comment: Ordenar la lista

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14051739/how-to-change-the-select-option-order este me sirvio :), por si alguien mas en el futuro lo busca.

Answer (score 0):

A pesar de que en los comentarios mencionas que lo haz conseguido, te dejo una forma mucho más sostenible en el tiempo, ya que si la cantidad de tallas aumenta (por ejemplo para zapatos, donde tendrás muchos valores a ordenar) se dificultará un poco la mantenibilidad.

La idea consiste en definir un atributo `data` para cada `option` y así definir su posición dentro del `select`, posteriormente solo llamarías a la función `orderById` pasando la id de un `select` que posea los atributos data y este los ordenará.

Para definir la posición simplemente actualiza el valor dentro del `data-position=""`

```js
function orderById (id){
  var select = $('#'+id)
  var elements = $('#'+id+' option')
  select.html("")
  for(i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
    elements.each((index, element) => {
      if($(element).data('position') == i){
        select.append(element)
      }
    })
  }
}
orderById('pa_talla')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="pa_talla" class="" name="attribute_pa_talla" data-attribute_name="attribute_pa_talla" data-show_option_none="yes">
  <option data-position="0" value="">Elige una opción</option>
  <option data-position="2" value="l" class="attached enabled">L</option>
  <option data-position="1" value="s" class="attached enabled">S</option>
  <option data-position="3" value="xl" class="attached enabled">XL</option>
</select>
```